# Oracle Solaris Studio memory leak with cout

Tags: c++

I'm using Oracle Solaris Studio for some memory tests. I just installed it, and wrote the traditional "Hello World" program to make sure all is up and running correctly.

However, the Memory leaks tool reports that operator new is leaking 40 bytes...

I read that this was a common problem in older versions of visual studio with the MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) but now I'm very confused because this in an Oracle product... right?

As I understand it can be ignored. But it is annoying to see it pop up every time just because I print something.

Can something be done about it?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
 std::cout<<"Hello World\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If their memory tool is as bad as their compiler, I wouldn't bother. Give valgrind a shot instead. But _just in case_, show us your actual code.

Comment: ohh... this is sad to hear, I thought this tool was promising :( So, are there any other free or open source IDEs that have this kind of profiler tools?

Comment: you lost me at 'Oracle Solaris Studio'

Comment: @user1274605 : If you don't need IDE integration then [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled with Sun Studio 12 and examined with TotalView:

There is indeed a heap allocation of 40 bytes without a matching deallocation, made by `__rwstd::facet_imp* __rwstd::facet_maker<std::codecvt<char,char,__mbstate_t>>::maker_func( int, const char*, unsigned )`, called by `__rwstd::facet_imp* std::locale::__make_explicit( const std::locale::id& ,bool, int, __rwstd::facet_imp*(*)(int,const char*,unsigned)) const`, called by `filebuf::overflow` called by `filebuf::sync` called by `operator<<`.

Note though that [Oracle recommends compiling](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cmp_stlport_libCstd.html) with `-library=stlport4` unless you need binary compatibility with something built against their roguewave-based libCstd. Compiled with this option, there are no heap allocations made in `main()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Purify** from IBM can detect memory leak, maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the Solaris Studio memory tool and found it to be quite helpful... and accurate, even when I thought I knew my code better than the tool. Perhaps the people who were so quick to denigrate the Solaris Studio Memory Tool would be willing to give it a try to see how much better it is than the suggested alternatives.